# Resolve a standalone string/file using typesafe config

Tags: scala, config, typesafe-config

I'm looking for a way to say:

```
val c: Config = ConfigFactory.parseString("a=fox,b=dog")
val s: String = """This is a "quick" brown ${a}.\nThat is a lazy, lazy ${b}."""
println(c.resolveString(s))

// Should print:
// > This is a "quick" brown fox.
// > That is a lazy lazy dog.
```

My two ideas:

- Just find the placeholders with regex and replace from config one by one
- convert `s` to config with single value and use `resolveWith` - but it seems quoting can be really tricky

Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: Any reason you don't just extract values "a" and "b" and pass them to the string interpolator?

Comment: I don't know this is exactly "a" and "b". It can be more variables, anything that comes in the config.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution:

```
class Resolver(vars: Config) {
  private lazy val placeholderRegex = "(?<=\\$\\{).*?(?=\\})".r

  def resolveString(s: String): String = {
    placeholderRegex.findAllIn(s).foldLeft(s) { (str, v) =>
      if (vars.hasPath(v)) str.replaceAll("\\Q${" + v + "}\\E", vars.getString(v)) else str
    }
  }
```

It should be fine if the string is not huge and there are no insane numbers of distinct placeholders in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation where I automatically push elastic search index definitions before 
I launch the job which uses those index definitions.

In my case the string which contains variable references is the 
JSON index/template definition, which ALSO comes from the typesafe config.
(see es.template_or_index.json, below.)

I resolve these refs using the utility method I wrote on top 
of apache.commons StrSubstitutor.

(see: VariableReferenceResolver.resolveReferences(String template), below)

Below is a sample of my config.  Note how the property 'es.animal' is injected into the index/template json.
This can't be done with out-of-the-box features of the typesafe config library  (but I think this would
be a wonderful feature for them to add !)

```
 es {
      // user and password credentials should not be checked in to git. deployer is expected to
      // set these parameters into the their environment in whatever way is convenient -- .bashrc or whatever.
      user = dummy
      user = ${?ES_USER}
      password = dummy.passwd
      password = ${?ES_PASSWORD}
      hostPort = "localhost:9200"
      hostPort = ${?ES_HOST_PORT}
      protocol = http
      protocol = ${?ES_PROTOCOL}

      animal = horse            // This gets injected into the configuration property es.template_or_index.json


      // Note: for template json there is a second round of interpolation performed so the json can reference any defined
      // property of this configuration file (or anything it includes)
      template_or_index {
        name = test_template
        json = """
      {
          "template": "${es.animal}_sql-*",
          "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 50,
            "number_of_replicas": 2
          },
          "mappings": {
                 "test_results" : {
                     "date_detection": false,
                     "properties" : {
                         "timestamp" : { "type" : "date"},
                         "yyyymmdd" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                     }
                 }
          }
        }
        """
      }
 }



package com.foo

import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrLookup;
import org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrSubstitutor;

public class VariableReferenceResolver {
    final StrSubstitutor substitutor;

    static class ConfigStrLookup extends StrLookup {
          private final Config config;

          ConfigStrLookup(Config config) {
              this.config = config;
          }

          public String lookup(String key) {
              return config.getString(key);
          }
      }

    public VariableReferenceResolver (Config config) {
        substitutor=new StrSubstitutor(new ConfigStrLookup(config));

    }

    public String resolveReferences(String template) {
        return substitutor.replace(template);
    }
}


public class OtherClass { 
    private static void getIndexConfiguration(String path) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("config.file", path);
        Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
        String user =  config.getString("es.user");
        String password =  config.getString("es.password");
        String protocol =  config.getString("es.protocol");
        String hostPort =  config.getString("es.hostPort");
        String indexOrTemplateJson = config.getString("es.template_or_index.json");
        String indexOrTemplateName = config.getString("es.template_or_index.name");
        VariableReferenceResolver resolver = new VariableReferenceResolver(config);
        String resolvedIndexOrTemplateJson = resolver.resolveReferences(indexOrTemplateJson);

        File jsonFile = File.createTempFile("index-or-template-json", indexOrTemplateName);
        Files.write(Paths.get(jsonFile.getAbsolutePath()), resolvedIndexOrTemplateJson.getBytes());

        curlIndexOrTemplateCreateCommand =
                String.format(
                        "curl  -XPUT  -k -u %s:%s %s://%s/_template/%s -d @%s",
                        user, password, protocol, hostPort, indexOrTemplateName,  jsonFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }


            ....
}
```